# make modification for other people pull request

Tags: git, github

How can i interact with pull request suggested by other people?

My situation

This happens in repository is not owned by me. 
some people(name Alex) makes pull request(name suggest1) for the repository. this pull request consists of commit c1,c2,c3. I have look through the codes and found some error. I fork my own repository from pull request repository(Alex/suggest1). I made new branch(me/suggest2) from c2 commit because of error issue. my work progress(c21,c22,c23....).

AFTER what should i do? I want show my implementation for other people in pull request page. 
should i make new pull request for original pull request repository(Alex/suggest1)? should i make new pull request for original repository? If i make new pull request, it can be shown in the same pull request page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Pull request from your `fork repo` to `upstream` (from where you forked) and show the changes you've done. It would be shown in the `same pull request page` of original repo.